# How to parse Json array object?

Tags: json, qt, c++11, c++14

I am trying to parse a Json file in Qt application but i am stuck at a point.
I have a json file which contains arrays with properties. Now i have a Category class which has a items as member variable. Now i would like to parse the properties and create a unique category object and under this object i would like to add the properties.

I have achieved this by hardcoding:

```
auto vehicle = std::make_unique<Item>("Coordinates");
vehicle->addEntry(std::make_unique<PropertyItem>("TODO", "x", PropertyType::FLOAT, false, *vehicle.get()));
categories.emplace_back(std::move(vehicle));

void Model::loadItemsFromJson() {
    // Vehicle
    QJsonObject obj = loadJsonFile(":/jsonfiles/vehicle.json");
    QJsonArray properties = obj["properties"].toArray();
   /// No idea here how to achive
}
```

Should i change the Json for better handling or could this be achieved easily?
Thank you

--------------------------EDIT---------------------

```
Now my json looks like this:
{
    "General": [{
            "Address": "TODO",
            "Readonly": false
        },
    ],
    "Coordinates": [{
            "Address": "TODO",
            "Readonly": false
        }
    ]
    ]
}
```

and my implementation:

```
QJsonObject obj = loadJsonFile(":/jsonfiles/vehicle.json");
QVariantMap map = obj.toVariantMap();
for (auto& m : map.keys()) {
// How to create objects??
}
```

Comment: The hardcoded data doesn't seem to match the JSON data. Does "test2" "x" correspond to "World Coordinates" "X"?

Comment: Changed. test2 is actually address and WorldCoordinates is the category. Like this: ScenarioPropertyItem(const QString &address, const QString &displayName, PropertyType type, bool readOnly, CategoryItem &parentItem);

Comment: If you are defining the structure of your JSON, I'd suggest it match the structure of you objects. `{"Categories":{ "General" : [{"Address" : "TODO", "Name" : "Name", "Type" : "string", "ReadOnly" : "true"}, ...], "World Coordinates" : [...] }`

Comment: Yes, i could do, could you provide suggestion in creating the objects like mentioned in hardcoding.

Comment: QVariantMap map = obj.toVariantMap();
    for (auto& m : map.keys()) {
        std::make_unique<CategoryItem>(m);
        qDebug() << (m);
    } How do i now create CategoryItem class and below it the subclass objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you structure your JSON like your objects, e.g.

```
{ 
"Categories" : {        
    "General" : [{
        "Address" : "TODO", 
        "Name" : "Name", 
        "Type" : "string", 
        "ReadOnly" : "true"
        }, ...], 
    "World Coordinates" : [...] 
}
```

Then you just parse out each `CategoryItem` and `ScenarioPropertyItem`

```
PropertyType toPropertyType(QJsonValue value); // forward declare

void ScenarioPropertiesModel::loadItemsFromJson() {
    // Vehicle
    QJsonObject obj = loadJsonFile(":/jsonfiles/vehicle.json")["Categories"].toObject();
    for (auto & cat : obj)
    {
        auto category = std::make_unique<CategoryItem>(cat.name());
        for (auto & prop : cat.value().toArray())
        {
            auto address = prop["Address"].toString();
            auto name = prop["Name"].toString();
            auto type = toPropertyType(prop["Type"]);
            auto readonly = prop["Readonly"].toBool();
            category->addEntry(std::make_unique<ScenarioPropertyItem>(address, name, type, readonly));
        }
        categories.emplace_back(std::move(category));
    }
}

PropertyType toPropertyType(QJsonValue value)
{
    static std::map<QString, PropertyType> propertyTypes = 
    { 
        { "float", PropertyType::FLOAT },
        { "string", PropertyType::String },
        // etc
    }
    return propertyTypes[value.toString()];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped out. But one point is that obj[cat] produces error saying it does not return an iterator.

Comment: You are the best, thank you. Should be like this :         for (auto& prop : obj[cat].toArray()) {
            auto address = prop.toObject().value("Address").toString();

Comment: You don't need the `toObject().value(...)`. `QJsonValue::operator[]` is defined to be equivalent

Comment: I would like to ask an additional question. Passing QJsonobject to a function per copy is heavy? Because i have something like this:     QJsonObject obj; Signature :     QJsonObject loadJsonFile(const QString& filePath);
    void parseJsonObject(QJsonObject object);
    obj = loadJsonFile(":/jsonfiles/vehicle.json");
    parseJsonObject(obj);
    // Pedestrian
    obj = loadJsonFile(":/jsonfiles/pedestrian.json");
    parseJsonObject(obj);
    // MiscObject
    obj = loadJsonFile(":/jsonfiles/miscobject.json");
    parseJsonObject(obj); or should i use pointer

Comment: @vinaycool All the `QJson...` classes are implicitly shared ("Copy-on-Write"), which means they are lightweight to pass around. If you qualify your parameters as `const`, then you can be confident they are not copied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177639/discussion-between-vinay-cool-and-caleth).

Comment: Here obj.keys() is giving me in a sorted order. Can we get in the original form as mentioned in the json file